# PickerView Default row selected but returns zero unless the picker view is moved

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, viewdidload

In my picker view I want the default row to be zero.  This row has a value of 1.  I want to be able to touch nothing on the view contoller except a button.  I know there are similar questions but they did not work for me.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.pickerView.delegate = self
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self


    self.pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)

      }


func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return String(numbers[row])
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.count

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

     therow = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0) + 1        
}
```

then

> @IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: Any) {
>   Print (therow)
>   }

When I tap submit and print the value at row 0 it is 0, but if I wiggle the picker view and put it back on row 0 then it prints 1.  I need to be able to touch nothing on the picker view and have it return the proper value of the default row.

Comment: I think you should use "theRowIndex = row" in didSelectRow method

Comment: theRowIndex is unknown @SaurabhPrajapati

Comment: Is `didSelectRow` called at all when you only press the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `row` that the **pickerview delegate** method gives you , so you should modify your code as follows:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

     therow = numbers[row]   
     //theRowIndex = row   //this is the index of row that you selected


}
```

e.g if `numbers` array is numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4],  when you click on first row above code will set `therow` to be 1 and if you click on second row, it will set `therow` to be 2 and so on.

if you want to use the code that you wrote then you can use as follows:

```
therow = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
```

this will give you the number for selected row , but I think you dont need it inside the above method.

Now if you dont want to touch the picker then I think you need to do this:

```
@IBAction func submitTapped(_ sender: Any) { 
       therow =  numbers[self.pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
       print(therow)

 }
```

Comment: Where did you get "theRowIndex" from it is unknown in my program @3stud1ant3

Comment: @MichaelR. my appologies, I only mentioned it as an example ,updated the answer, see if it helps you

Answer (score 1):

Use this statement once you load your picker view with data.

```
yourPicker.selectRow(0, inComponent:0, animated:true)
```

You can change the default selected value by changing the first parameter of selectRow.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why this happens is that `didSelectRow` is somehow not called if you selected the row programmatically. As per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614371-pickerview):

> Called by the picker view when the ***user*** selects a row in a component.

So you need to set your `therow` property programmatically after you call `selectRow`:

```
self.pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
therow = 1 // <--- this line
```